# How to select CustomerName and average ProductPrice

Tags: sql, oracle

For a homework problem I have these tables are provided:

```
Product
-ProductID(Key)
-ProductName
-ProductPrice
-VendorID
-CategoryID

SoldVia
-ProductID(Key)
-TID(FK)
-NoOfItems

SalesTransaction
-TID(Key)
-TDate
-CustomerID(FK)
-StoreID(FK)

Customer
-CustomerID(Key)
-CustomerName
-CustomerZip
```

And I am supposed to select the CustomerName and average price for each customer. I am confused as to how to only average the productprices of the productID's that a specific customer bought.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerName, AVG(Product.ProductPrice)
FROM Customer, Product
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID
                            FROM SalesTransaction
                            WHERE TID = (SELECT TID 
                                        FROM SoldVia
                                        WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID
                                                          FROM Product)));
```

Comment: add a group by clause on customerName to your query for aggregating the results per customer

Comment: @Sahil - I hope that's not how you use GROUP BY. The OP's data has customer id as primary key. If you group by customer **name** you will get wrong answers if you have two or three or more clients called John Smith, or Sahil Khan. That is *exactly* why you need primary keys on most tables, which are **not** part of the business-meaningful data (such as customer names).

Comment: @mathguy you are absolutely correct, we need to do it on customerId.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
select c.customername, 
       sum(sv.noofitems  * p.productprice) / sum(sv.noofitems) as avg_price
from   customer c join salestransaction st on  c.customerid = st.customerid
                  join soldvia          sv on st.tid        = sv.tid
                  join product          p  on sv.productid  =  p.productid
group  by c.customerid
;
```

This will not return customers that bought nothing at all. If you must include those customers too (with NULL for the average price - nothing else makes sense), then you will need to change all the `join` to `left outer join`.

Note that "average price" is a **weighted** average (weighted by the number of units - the quantity - purchased for each distinct product), and therefore it **can't** be computed with the standard aggregate function `avg()`.